# java.lang.ClassCastException: android.os.BinderProxy cannot be cast to com.leonard.sg.okcoin.service.SyncAndTradeService$SyncAndTradeBinder

Tags: java, android, foreground-service

I tried to bind the MainActivity to a foreground service, then got the following Exceptions, already searched more than one hour, no idea what i did wrongly, pls save me.

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: android.os.BinderProxy cannot be cast to com.leonard.sg.okcoin.service.SyncAndTradeService$SyncAndTradeBinder
        at com.leonard.sg.okcoin.MainActivity$1.onServiceConnected(MainActivity.java:50)
        at android.app.LoadedApk$ServiceDispatcher.doConnected(LoadedApk.java:1101)
        at android.app.LoadedApk$ServiceDispatcher$RunConnection.run(LoadedApk.java:1118)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5227)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:795)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:562)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

The code in my MainActivity:

```
private SyncAndTradeService syncAndTradeService;
private boolean hasBounded = false;

private Intent syncAndTradeServiceIntent;

private ServiceConnection syncAndTradeServiceConnection = new ServiceConnection() {
    @Override
    public void onServiceConnected(ComponentName name, IBinder service) {
        SyncAndTradeService.SyncAndTradeBinder syncAndTradeBinder = (SyncAndTradeService.SyncAndTradeBinder) service;
        syncAndTradeService = syncAndTradeBinder.getSyncAndTradeService();
        hasBounded = true;
    }

    @Override
    public void onServiceDisconnected(ComponentName name) {
        syncAndTradeService = null;
        hasBounded = false;
    }
};
```

And i tried to do this in onCreate method:

```
syncAndTradeServiceIntent = new Intent(this, SyncAndTradeService.class);

bindService(syncAndTradeServiceIntent, syncAndTradeServiceConnection, Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);
```

And this is my service code:

```
public class SyncAndTradeService extends Service {

    public static final int MY_FOREGROUND_SERVICE_START_ID = 996539;

    private IBinder syncAndTradeBinder = new SyncAndTradeBinder();

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {

        startSyncAndTradeService();

        return Service.START_REDELIVER_INTENT;
    }

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return syncAndTradeBinder;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onUnbind(Intent intent) {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public void onRebind(Intent intent) {
        super.onRebind(intent);
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
    }

    public class SyncAndTradeBinder extends Binder {

        public SyncAndTradeService getSyncAndTradeService() {
            return SyncAndTradeService.this;
        }

    }

    private void startSyncAndTradeService() {
        startForeground(MY_FOREGROUND_SERVICE_START_ID, buildFixedNotification());
    }

    private Notification buildFixedNotification() {

        Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);

        notificationIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);

        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, notificationIntent, 0);

        Notification notification = new Notification.Builder(this)
            .setContentTitle("OKCoin Robot")
            .setContentText("OKCoin robot is running in background")
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.bitcoin)
            .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
            .build();

        return notification;
    }

}
```

And this is my declaration of my service in the Manifest.xml

```
<service
    android:name=".service.SyncAndTradeService"
    android:exported="false"
    android:icon="@drawable/bitcoin"
    android:process=":SyncAndTrade">
</service>
```

Answer (score 19, accepted):

can't wait, so kept researching when i was free for the whole day, fortunately found the solution, hope this can help some beginners like me.

- if u run the service in the same process with ur application, that means u should declare the service in the Manifest.xml without 'android:process', if u do this, then the above absolutely works fine.
- the above exception will be threw when u try to bind ur app component to a service which is run in a different process
- so the solution is wrapping ur IBinder with AIDL.
- following is the code based the above one

**define ur AIDL interface**

```
package com.leonard.sg.okcoin.service.robot.aidl;

interface ISyncAndTradeService {

    boolean startTradeEngine();

}
```

**then change the onBind method in ur service to this:**

```
@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    return new ISyncAndTradeService.Stub() {

        @Override
        public boolean startTradeEngine() throws RemoteException {
            return false;
        }
    };
}
```

**then refine the build service connection class to this:**

```
private ISyncAndTradeService syncAndTradeService;
private boolean hasBounded = false;

private Intent syncAndTradeServiceIntent;

private ServiceConnection syncAndTradeServiceConnection = new ServiceConnection() {
    @Override
    public void onServiceConnected(ComponentName name, IBinder service) {
        syncAndTradeService = ISyncAndTradeService.Stub.asInterface((IBinder) service);
        hasBounded = true;
    }

    @Override
    public void onServiceDisconnected(ComponentName name) {
        syncAndTradeService = null;
        hasBounded = false;
    }
};
```

**then everything will work fine**

but this raise another problem, according to the google documentation of the attribute 'android:process' of service declaration, we can do this:

> android:process
>   The name of the process where the service is to run. Normally, all components of an application run in the default process created for the application. It has the same name as the application package. The  element's process attribute can set a different default for all components. But component can override the default with its own process attribute, allowing you to spread your application across multiple processes.
>   If the name assigned to this attribute begins with a colon (':'), a new process, private to the application, is created when it's needed and the service runs in that process. If the process name begins with a lowercase character, the service will run in a global process of that name, provided that it has permission to do so. This allows components in different applications to share a process, reducing resource usage.

**but in practice, if i declare the 'android:process' start with character, no matter lowercase or uppercase, i will get this error:**

```
DEVICE SHELL COMMAND: pm install -r "/data/local/tmp/com.leonard.sg.okcoin"
pkg: /data/local/tmp/com.leonard.sg.okcoin
Failure [INSTALL_PARSE_FAILED_MANIFEST_MALFORMED]
```

**the only choice is start with ':' or '.'**

Answer (score 0):

I just remove the below line in my activity. it is working fine.
android:process=":UsbEventReceiverActivityProcess"